# Difference in Javascript Date object

Tags: javascript, object, date

Depending on how you create a Date object a different timestamp is returned.

```
var g1 = new Date(2011, 6, 18, 14, 50, 0);
var g2 = new Date("June 18, 2011 14:50:00");
alert(g1.getTime() + "\n" + g2.getTime());

// velue alerted is 
1310997000000
1308405000000
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation for [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> month
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December

You are passing 6 for the month, so the constructor interprets it as July.

Both of these values should be identical:

```
var g1 = new Date(2011, 5, 18, 14, 50, 0);
var g2 = new Date("June 18, 2011 14:50:00"); 

alert(g1.getTime() + "\n" + g2.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This makes perfect sense now.

Comment: You're welcome. Its always fun dealing with those little off-by-one errors when working with date/time :)